# Css intellisense doesn't work after django extension

Tags: css, django, visual-studio-code, intellisense

after i install django extension on VScode css intellisense stop works in .html
but in .css it's fine[image]

this is .html and css intellisense doesnt' but

[image]

in the .css all work fine
how can i fix this problem?

Comment: Restart VS Code or you can disable the Django extension during CSS work.

Comment: Restaring vs code doesnt work,any other optional then disable the extension during css work?

Comment: No, I haven't a better idea for this problem.